# Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality(e.g.editing,debugging..) in Android studio 2.3.1

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I Cannot run the project, i have checked many sites & stack overflow nothing happended.  **Gradle DSL method not found:'compile()** & **The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin** '[image: Click here to see my Screenshot].

build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "info.devexchanges.bluetoothchatapp"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:21'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

}
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
    apply plugin: 'announce'

    apply plugin: 'build-announcements'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'


}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Can you try adding the plugins from your build.gradle to your app/build.gradle just below the dependency body? If that doesn't work, try placing the plugins at the top of the file.

Comment: i tried , but not working.

Answer (score 1):

find and replace this code

private final BroadcastReceiver discoveryFinishReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

```
    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
            String recieverAddress = device.getName();
            String recieverPassword = device.getAddress();
            et_tnum.setText(recieverAddress);
            et_pass.setText(recieverPassword);
        }
    } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
        if (discoveredDevicesAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
            discoveredDevicesAdapter.add(getString(R.string.none_found));
        }
    }
}
```

};

Hope you got this!

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. i tried your idea. but receiver side nothing happening, only sender side its entered automatically, i dont want that. the receiver phone should receive those string into the edittext. i will post my code.. please help me

Comment: im getting error in enableIntent.putExtra("accountNumber", et_tnum); enableIntent.putExtra("password", et_pass);

Comment: `  public void onClick (View v)
    {

        Intent i=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        enableIntent.putExtra("accountNumber",et_tnum);
        enableIntent.putExtra("password",et_pass);

        String accountNumber = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("accountNumber");
        String password = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("password");



        et_tnum.setText(accountNumber);
        et_pass.setText(password);


    }` & i dont knw how to use intent

Comment: In your case intent is i so replace enableIntent with i.

Comment: Are you new to android

Comment: I suggest you to go through newboston on android tutorial before starting a project.

Comment: yeah im learning, nd doing mca project. Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details. i got this error

Comment: So intent which is used to start an activity you set an intent with this and a target activity class and then you start activity with the intent you assigned, now you add data such as string or integer or a bunch using put intent.putextra(); and in the target activity you retrieve the intent data by assigning it to a string or integer

Comment: You are setting the intent extras and retrieving the extras in the same method which is giving you the error

Comment: but here im using two seperate application one is for sending string, another one is for receive the string into corresponding edittext, there is no more activity in a app just single activity ..only thing is string should be send using bluetooth, please see my above application design i've updated

Comment: How are  you receiving those two strings in the receivers layout

Comment: using listview.actually my project is after received those strings i need to verify with server

Comment: I dint got you that ok where are you saving the strings

Comment: no earlier i did register,login user data using local host, now i need to do with actual server, Now i dont hav server. this is my task,

Comment: my problem is , string will be successfully received, but not in the edittext. is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible you just need to set that received string inside edit text.

Comment: yeah correct that is what i want.any idea about that

Comment: can you post where are you receiving the strings

Comment: i've updated my xml file. actually it is two way communication using blutooth adapter.. for my case the receiver no need to send the string back , only he needs to receive.the above java code for receiver side, he cant send back

Comment: bro how otp automatically entered,can i try that method